# Reboots taking an hour due to fsck

Tags: boot, fsck

I'm running into an issue where reboots on two of my application servers are taking about an hour each time. I think that an fsck is happening each time but I cannot find much information in the logs to help debug.

In dmesg I'm seeing the following:

```
[    8.081130] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[   10.776403] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   10.776409] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[   10.776413] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: EEE is enabled
[   10.776448] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   11.771117] tg3 0000:02:00.1 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   11.771124] tg3 0000:02:00.1 eth1: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[   11.771127] tg3 0000:02:00.1 eth1: EEE is enabled
[   11.771173] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[ 3171.529473] FS-Cache: Loaded
[ 3171.549333] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[ 3171.549334] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[ 3171.549335] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[ 3171.549335] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[ 3171.566048] init: failsafe main process (1506) killed by TERM signal
[ 3171.576544] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[ 3171.685710] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
[ 3171.871112] audit_printk_skb: 6 callbacks suppressed
```

which corresponds to the same amount of time by boot takes.

I'm wondering if anyone has ideas on where to start investigating?

The machines are:
Dell Poweredge R420
Ubuntu 14.04

lsblk:

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 558.4G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5                      8:5    0 558.1G  0 part
  ├─app2-root (dm-0)   252:0    0 542.2G  0 lvm  /
  └─app2-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0  15.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

fstab:

```
proc                     /proc  proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/app2-root /      ext4    errors=remount-ro             0 1
UUID=8a2c24e5-17ba-4992-82a1-68b9609b6983 /boot   ext2    defaults 0 2
/dev/mapper/hd1app2-swap_1 none    swap    sw           0       0
```

### Edit

This turned out to NOT be related to fsck at all. The issue was that there were Gigabytes of data in the /tmp which were cleared each time on boot. Note the gap between 11.771173 and 3171.529473 in the logs. Too bad dmesg doesn't display anything for useful for this particular scenario.

Comment: Output 'dmesg -T' to see human timestamp. Usually ubuntu runs fsck every boot when it really finds disk issues or when system time is outdated.

Comment: See `man -k smart` to find disk health utilities. `fsck`, run once, should fix the disk problem or fail to mount the disk. Needing to `fsck` again hints at a permanent disk failure, disk misuse, or as @Redbob said, system time issues. I use `dmesg --kernel --ctime --userspace --decode`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Is there anyway to get the human timestamps from the /var/log files? The reboot happened a few days so the info is not in the kernel dmesg. Also, am I using the -T flag to determine if the system time is outdated or is there another way to check for this?

Comment: @waltinator Looks like the device lacks SMART capability. Any other way to  detect errors? The Dell management software reports that there are no errors fwiw.